# Scanning the C Directory with Scandir

Tags: php, directory, scandir

In PHP I am trying to use the `scandir()` method to get all of the directories in `C:`.  However, I keep getting the error that the directory does not exist.

> Error: scandir(C:): failed to open dir: No such file or directory

My code is as follows:

```
$content = scandir('C:');
```

Could the issue be caused by my code being in a directory checked out of SVN?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `Error: scandir(C:\): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`

Comment: if your code is running off C:, then skip the whole drive letter entirely. `scandir('/')` would work just as well.

Comment: check for permissions and if running off as admin, could be that. or try what Marc said.

Comment: @MarcB  Basically my code is running off of `C:\sandbox\workspace\Admin` and my ultimate goal is to scan a different local directory, `C:\sandbox\workspace\config\branch\project`, with the second path being passed in as a variable so I was hoping I could just pass in the full path.  So I have to convert it to have `..\..` in order to make it work?

Comment: you can build the path however you want. an absolute `scandir('/sandbox/workspace/etc...')` would work too.

Comment: @MarcB `scandir('/sandbox/workspace/config/branch/project'); ` yields  `Error: scandir(/sandbox/workspace/config/branch/project): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`

Comment: have you tried `C:\\sandbox\\workspace\\config\\branch\\project` or even with 3 backslashes if that's the path you really want to scan? Lordie, something's gotta give. and check permissions on all folders.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same error -_-  How would I know that I have permissions? I can access it through my file browser, so should I be able to access it through the code?

Comment: That I couldn't say. I'm a * NIX guy so my knowledge of Windows webservers is very limited.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks anyway! I'll look more into permissions

Comment: You're welcome. Wishing you well, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this example:

```
$files1 = scandir("C:\\");
print_r($files1);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: `Error: scandir(C:\): failed to open dir: No such file or directory`

Comment: I said that already, and should be in single quotes on top of that. Just because my comment got an upvote, doesn't mean you'll get one too.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I think we're getting an *`@ echo off`* there Sam @JayBlanchard

Comment: @tibsar At this [link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php#114184) is a solution maybe, that overload scandir. This could be help in what you are looking to do, let me know if this worked for you.